# Conditional Probability HW Question Semantics

Tags: probability

I have a question related to the wording of a basic probability problem which I have partially completed. Specifically, I have trouble wrapping my head around the English statement highlighted in **bold** in order to make a comparison.

The problem statement is as follows:

A coin is tossed twice. **Alice claims that the event of two heads is at least as likely if we know that the first toss is a head than if we know that at least one of the tosses is a head. Is she correct?**

My solution to the problem thus far is as follows:

Visualizing sample space of the random experiment makes it easy to compute the conditional probabilities.

$$ \Omega = \{(H1,H2),(H1,T2),(T1,H2),(T1,T2)\} $$

The probability of a second head given the first head happened is as follows:

$$ P(H2|H1) = \frac{P(two \; heads)}{P(head \; on \; the \; first \; toss)} =\frac{1/4}{2/4} = \frac{1}{2} $$

while the event another head happens given a head occus in the two coin toss happens is

$$ P(two \; heads | a \; head \; occurred ) = \frac{P(two \; heads \; occurring)}{P(a \; head \; occurred) } = \frac{1/4}{3/4} = \frac{1}{3} $$

Would it be possible for somebody to restate the problem statement for me in a different way? I do not understand how to compare the two likelihoods I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alice claims that $P(H2|H1) \ge P(\text{two heads}|\text{a head occurred})$. You verified that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement haven't said anything about whether the tosses are equally likely (nothing is said about the die fairness), so you cannot as of yet use the fact that the probability of every elementary event is $1/4$.

Consider the following events :

A = { the first roll is HEAD}

B = { the second roll is HEAD }

The general answer can be obtained by comparing the quantities :

- $P(A \cap B | A)$ => given that the first roll is head what is the probability that both rolls are head
- $P(A \cap B | A \cup B )$ => given that at least one of the rolls is head what is the probability that the two rolls are head

$\to P(A \cap B | A) = P (A \cap B) / P(A)$

$\to P(A \cap B | A \cup B ) = P (A \cap B) / P(A \cup B)$

since $P(A \cup B) \geq P(A)$ we clearly have :

$P(A \cap B | A) \geq P(A \cap B | A \cup B )$ , and hence Alice claim is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. It's better to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) to make the equations readable. Furthermore, it's easier if you try to use the notation of the original post. Other than that, thanl you for your answer.